# onedit apps script for having only one checkbox ticked

Tags: google-apps-script, checkbox, range

I found the onEdit script below for only one checkbox being ticked at a time and uncheck all others, when a new checkbox is ticked.
Unfortunately I don´t know how to modify this script for a cell range A5:A1000. For two cells it works fine in the A1 notation ['A13','B13'], but ['A5:A1000'] doesn´t work.
Any ideas?
Thanks a lot!

```
function onEdit(e) {
  
  const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const cell = e.range.getA1Notation();
  const cell_checks = ['A13','B13'];
  if(as.getName() == "Sheet1" && cell_checks.includes(cell) && e.range.isChecked())
  {cell_checks.filter(val=>val!=cell).forEach(c=>as.getRange(c).uncheck())}  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry")
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const cell = e.range.getA1Notation();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet1" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart > 4 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    //e.source.toast("GATE1")
    let o = sh.getRange(5, 1, 996).getValues().flat().map((v, i) => {
      if (i + 5 != e.range.rowStart) {
        return ["FALSE"];
      } else {
        return ["TRUE"];
      }
    });
    sh.getRange(5, 1, o.length).setValues(o);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Cooper, script works like a charm! The next hours I will spend with trying to understand your script :D. Again, thanks!